# Salesforce apex class Unexpected token error

Tags: salesforce

I want to create a keyword search referring to "UserName__c" api on Salesforce Apex class.

compile error Unexpected token 'UserName__c'.

```
public with sharing class AccountListCon {

    static List<String> TARGET_FIELDS = new List<String>{
      'Name'
      ,'UserName__c'
      ,'CompanyName__c'
    };

    public SearchCondition condition{ get;set; }        
    public String UserName__c results { get;set; }      
    public String sortingField { get;set; }             



    public void init(){
        this.condition = new SearchCondition();
        this.results = new String UserName__c();
    }


    public PageReference clear(){
        init();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such type `String UserName__c`. It's not entirely clear what you want to do here, but I suspect you intend just to declare a `String` variable. The fact that you're looking for values in some field whose API name is `UserName__c` is not relevant to the type system

Answer (score 0):

`public String UserName__c results { get;set; }`   is wrong. Is this supposed to be just
`public String results { get;set; }` ?